# How to plot color as function of a third variable using matplotlib.scatter?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter

I want to plot Points with x and y-Values and colour them depending on a corresponding time value. Data is stored in a Dataframe.

The solution should be the `c`-parameter of matplotlib's `scatter` function, but for some reason its not working for me.
The times-column is a List of float values between 0 and 3.
Plotting the Points without `c`-parameter is working.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

c=list(df_result_local['times'])
for i in range(len(df_result_local['Points'])):
    plt.scatter(df_result_local['Points'][i].x, df_result_local['Points'][i].y, c=c, alpha = 0.5)
```

Here I get a ValueError: 'c' argument has 1698 elements, which is not acceptable for use with 'x' with size 1, 'y' with size 1.

Comment: Well your error states, that your x and y axis have a length of 1, while c has a length of 1698. So you probably have to convert x and y to lists as well.

Comment: You need to convert c[i] to a color of your liking. See https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html  Viridis is often considered an optimal map.

Comment: x,y are the same? I mean, if x = 0, y = 0 and x = 5, y =5 and so on? You are getting x and y from the same pandas column, it's not wrong, but it's a bit weirdo.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

c=list(df_result_local['times'])
x = []
y = []
for i in range(len(df_result_local['Points'])):
    x.append(df_result_local['Points'][i].x)
    y.append(df_result_local['Points'][i].y)

plt.scatter(df_result_local['Points'][i].x, df_result_local['Points'][i].y, c=c, alpha = 0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the index on `c` as well. So

```
plt.scatter(df_result_local['Points'][i].x, df_result_local['Points'][i].y, c=c[i], alpha = 0.5)
```

Comment: I tried this allready: I get error: tuple index out of range. df_result_local['times'][0] --> 0.31, type(df_result_local['times'][0]) --> numpy.float64

Comment: As it is said in other notes, you need to have same size for c and your data

Comment: It is the same size but the point was to handle x and y as lists as well. Thnak you!